# O que é o Static em Java? E Como usá-lo?

Tags: java, static

Como Posso usar o **Static** em Java? e pra que ele serve? *Qual sua Função?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tirado [daqui](https://www.guj.com.br/t/para-que-serve-a-palavra-static/42731/4?u=piovezan).

Em Java, você pode ter 3 coisas “static”: blocos de inicialização, variáveis/métodos e classes internas.

Primeiro precisa entender o seguinte. Static é a mesma coisa que “de classe”, e não “de objeto”. Uma classe pode ter vários objetos. Por exemplo:

```
Carro vectra = new Carro();
Carro palio = new Carro();
```

Aqui temos apenas uma classe: “Carro”
Mas temos dois objetos: “vectra” e “palio”

Agora que já sabe a diferença entre classe e objeto, fica mais fácil. Static é “de classe”, ou seja, uma variável static da classe Carro teria o mesmo valor para qualquer objeto (vectra, palio, fusca, ferrari…). Tanto que você nem precisa criar objetos pra acessá-las. Ela é usada geralmente para contadores, ver quantos objetos foram criados a partir da classe, ou então para fazer variáveis globais.

Se você não coloca static nas variáveis, elas ficam com uma cópia diferente pra cada objeto (o que é o mais usual).

Blocos de inicialização são bloquinhos com coisas que você quer que executem quando a classe for carregada na virtual machine, o que acontece apenas uma vez (é bem pouco usado, é mais só pra saber que existe). Por exemplo:

```
static {
    System.out.println("O classloader carregou essa classe!!");
}
```

E classes internas são classes dentro de classes, que também podem ser static (também pouco usado, mas saiba que existe). Por exemplo:

```
class Externa {

    static class Interna {

    }

}
```

Utilidade do static: veja seus usos nos métodos e campos da classe [Math](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html) do Java, que é uma classe sem estado interno.