# Como fazer o for instanciar um novo objeto JAVA

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, for

Estou nas minhas primeiras aulas de programação orientada a objeto e estou tendo dificuldade em uma avaliação.

Crie uma classe com pelo menos 10 atributos para a criação de objetos do tipo Computador. A classe deve possuir pelo menos 10 métodos construtores, métodos de acesso (setters e getters) e os métodos de entrada de dados e de exibição (imprimir). Crie também uma aplicação que gere pelo menos seis objetos do tipo Computador, utilizando diferentes métodos construtores para cada objeto criado. Apresente os resultados dos testes realizados no ambiente de desenvolvimento.

O código que escrevi é esse, porém não estou conseguindo fazer com que a cada preenchimento o **for**
instancie um novo objeto. O que eu poderia fazer para conseguir fazer isso?

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AVA1 {
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

private String placaMae;
private String processador;
private String gabinete;
private String placaDeVideo;
private String mouse;
private String teclado;
private String headset;
private int memoria;
private int monitor;
private double preco;
private DecimalFormat formatador = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
    
public void setPlacaMae(String mob) {
    if (!mob.isEmpty()) {
        this.placaMae = mob;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Fabricante incorreto\n");
        System.out.println("Frabricante da placa mãe: ");
        setPlacaMae(sc.nextLine());
    }
}
public String getPlacaMae() {
    return this.placaMae;
}

public void setProcessador(String cpu) {
    if (!cpu.isEmpty()) {
        this.processador = cpu;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Fabricante incorreto\n");
        System.out.println("Modelo do processador: ");
        setProcessador(sc.nextLine());
   }
}   
public String getProcessador() {
    return this.processador;
}

public void setGabinete(String gab) {
    if (!gab.isEmpty()) {
        this.gabinete = gab;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Fabricante incorreto\n");
        System.out.println("Frabricante do gabinete: ");
        setGabinete(sc.nextLine());
    }
}
public String getGabinete() {
    return this.gabinete;
}

public void setPlacaDeVideo(String vga) {
    if (!vga.isEmpty()) {
        this.placaDeVideo = vga;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Fabricante incorreto\n");
        System.out.println("Modelo da placa de video: ");
        setPlacaDeVideo(sc.nextLine());
    }
}
public String getPlacaDeVideo() {
    return this.placaDeVideo;
}

public void setMouse(String mou) {
    if (!mou.isEmpty()) {
        this.mouse = mou;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Fabricante incorreto\n");
        System.out.println("Modelo do mouse: ");
        setMouse(sc.nextLine());
    }
}
public String getMouse() {
    return this.mouse;
}

public void setTeclado(String tec) {
    if (!tec.isEmpty()) {
        this.teclado = tec;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Fabricante incorreto\n");
        System.out.println("Modelo do teclado: ");
        setTeclado(sc.nextLine());
    }
}
public String getTeclado() {
    return this.teclado;
}

public void setHeadset(String hst) {
    if (!hst.isEmpty()) {
        this.headset = hst;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Fabricante incorreto\n");
        System.out.println("Modelo do headset: ");
        setHeadset(sc.nextLine());
    }
}
public String getHeadset() {
    return this.headset;
}

public void setMemoria(int ram) {
    if (ram >= 1) {
        this.memoria = ram;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Valor inválido, informe um valor acima de 1 GB!\n");
        System.out.println("Quantidade de memória: ");
        setMemoria(Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine()));
    }
}
public int getMemoria() {
    return this.memoria;
}

public void setMonitor(Integer scr) {
    if (scr > 10) {
        this.monitor = scr;
} else {
    System.out.println("Tamanho do monitor muito pequeno!\n");
    System.out.println("Tamanho do monitor: ");
    setMonitor(Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine()));
    }
}
public int getMonitor() {
    return this.monitor;
}

public void setPreco(double prc) {
    this.preco = prc;
}
public double getPreco() {
    return this.preco;
}



public class Dados {
    private AVA1 meuComputador;
    public void entradaDados(AVA1 novoComputador) {
        
        
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        for( int i=0; i < 2; i++) { 
        System.out.println("Frabricante da placa mãe: ");
        setPlacaMae(sc.nextLine());

        System.out.println("Modelo do processador: ");
        setProcessador(sc.nextLine());

        System.out.println("Frabricante do gabinete: ");
        setGabinete(sc.nextLine());

        System.out.println("Modelo da placa de video: ");
        setPlacaDeVideo(sc.nextLine());

        System.out.println("Modelo do mouse: ");
        setMouse(sc.nextLine());

        System.out.println("Modelo do teclado: ");
        setTeclado(sc.nextLine());

        System.out.println("Modelo do headset: ");
        setHeadset(sc.nextLine());

        System.out.println("Quantidade de memória: ");
        setMemoria(Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine()));

        System.out.println("Tamanho do monitor: ");
        setMonitor(Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine()));

        System.out.println("Preco do Computador: ");
        setPreco(Double.parseDouble(sc.nextLine()));
        System.out.println("");
        
        }
        this.meuComputador = novoComputador;
        sc.close();
    }
    
    public AVA1 imprimir() {
        
        System.out.println("Placa mãe: " + getPlacaMae());
        System.out.println("Processador: " + getProcessador());
        System.out.println("Gabinete: " + getGabinete());
        System.out.println("Placa de video: " + getPlacaDeVideo());
        System.out.println("Mouse: " + getMouse());
        System.out.println("Teclado: " + getTeclado());
        System.out.println("Headset: " + getHeadset());
        System.out.println("Memória ram: " + getMemoria() + "GB");
        System.out.println("Tamanho da tela: " + getMonitor() + "'");
        System.out.println("Preço: R$ " + formatador.format(getPreco()) + "\n\n");
        return this.meuComputador;
    }
}
    
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
    AVA1 meuComputador = new AVA1();
    Dados config = meuComputador.new Dados();
    
    meuComputador.setPlacaMae("Placa Mãe");
    meuComputador.setProcessador("Processador");
    meuComputador.setGabinete("Gabinete");
    meuComputador.setPlacaDeVideo("Placa de Video");
    meuComputador.setMouse("Mouse");
    meuComputador.setTeclado("Teclado");
    meuComputador.setHeadset("Headset");
    meuComputador.setMemoria(1);
    meuComputador.setMonitor(20);
    meuComputador.setPreco(0.00);
    
    config.entradaDados(meuComputador);
    config.imprimir();
    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiramente, se a classe deve representar um computador, então eu sugiro que ela tenha um nome adequado (`Computador`, talvez?) - apesar de parecer um detalhe bobo, [dar nomes melhores ajuda muito na hora de programar](https://hackernoon.com/the-art-of-naming-variables-52f44de00aad).

E não precisaria desta classe `Dados` dentro de `AVA1`. [Leia aqui](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html) para entender melhor sobre *inner classes* - é um tópico um pouco mais avançado e como você disse que está nas primeiras aulas, deixe isso para depois. Tente fazer o simples (até porque nas primeiras aulas, provavelmente só vão pedir coisas simples mesmo).

Outro ponto é a separação de responsabilidades. Os métodos *setters* estão ao mesmo tempo setando a informação e pedindo que se digite novamente. Não acho que a entrada de dados deva estar misturada com a lógica de setar/validar um campo. Da forma que você fez, o código fica dependende do `Scanner` (mas e se os dados vierem de outro lugar, como um arquivo, por exemplo?).

Então primeiro vamos separar as responsabilidades. Crie uma classe `Computador`, que representa um único computador. Ela só tem as informações referentes ao computador, e só (os campos, a lógica de criação, etc).

```
public class Computador {
    private String placaMae;
    private String processador;
    ... coloque todos os campos aqui (exceto o Scanner e o DecimalFormat, que não tem nada a ver com o computador em si)

    public String getPlacaMae() {
        return placaMae;
    }

    public void setPlacaMae(String placaMae) {
        this.placaMae = placaMae;
    }

    // demais getters e setters...
}
```

---

### Imprimir os dados

Quanto a imprimir os dados, uma opção seria o próprio computador imprimir os seus dados. Para isso, crie um método na própria classe `Computador`:

```
public class Computador {
    // campos, getters, setters, etc..

    public void imprimir() {
        System.out.println("Placa mãe: " + this.placaMae);
        System.out.println("Processador: " + this.processador);
        System.out.println("Gabinete: " + this.gabinete);
        System.out.println("Placa de video: " + this.placaDeVideo);
        System.out.println("Mouse: " + this.mouse);
        System.out.println("Teclado: " + this.teclado);
        System.out.println("Headset: " + this.headset);
        System.out.printf("Memória ram: %dGB\n", this.memoria);
        System.out.printf("Tamanho da tela: %d'\n", this.monitor);
        System.out.printf("Preço: R$ %.2f\n\n", this.preco);
    }
}
```

Repare nos 3 últimos campos, usei `printf` em vez de concatenar strings, para mostrar que existe esta opção (no último caso, ainda coloquei `%.2f` para garantir que o valor é mostrado com 2 casas decimais). [Veja a documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax) para mais detalhes.

Se quiser, pode usar também um [`NumberFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/text/NumberFormat.html) para formatar um valor monetário:

```
public class Computador {
    // campos, getters, setters, etc..

    private static NumberFormat FORMATADOR_PRECO = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(new Locale("pt", "BR"));

    public void imprimir() {
        // imprime os outros campos (igual ao código anterior)
        System.out.printf("Preço: %s\n\n", FORMATADOR_PRECO.format(this.preco));
    }
}
```

O uso do [`Locale`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Locale.html) "pt-BR" (português do Brasil) garante que será usado a moeda "R$", além de usar a vírgula como separador decimal e o ponto para separar os milhares. Assim o valor é impresso como `R$ 3.599,99` por exemplo.

Como o `NumberFormat` é `static`, ele não é um campo do `Computador` (é criada uma única instância para todos os computadores). [Leia aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/463166/112052), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/241248/112052), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/17015/112052) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/54012/112052) para entender melhor.

---

### Criar as instâncias

Tendo isso, você pode fazer o seu *loop* criar um computador novo a cada iteração. Algo assim:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        Computador c = new Computador(); // cria um novo computador
        System.out.println("Fabricante da placa mãe: ");
        c.setPlacaMae(sc.nextLine());

        System.out.println("Modelo do processador: ");
        c.setProcessador(sc.nextLine());

        System.out.println("Frabricante do gabinete: ");
        c.setGabinete(sc.nextLine());

        System.out.println("Modelo da placa de video: ");
        c.setPlacaDeVideo(sc.nextLine());

        System.out.println("Modelo do mouse: ");
        c.setMouse(sc.nextLine());

        System.out.println("Modelo do teclado: ");
        c.setTeclado(sc.nextLine());

        System.out.println("Modelo do headset: ");
        c.setHeadset(sc.nextLine());

        System.out.println("Quantidade de memória: ");
        c.setMemoria(Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine()));

        System.out.println("Tamanho do monitor: ");
        c.setMonitor(Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine()));

        System.out.println("Preco do Computador: ");
        c.setPreco(Double.parseDouble(sc.nextLine()));

        System.out.println("\n\nCriado o computador:");
        c.imprimir();
    }
}
```

Ou seja, no início de cada iteração eu crio um computador, depois vou lendo os dados e setando-os. E no final eu imprimo os dados.

Como é um exercício, não sei se é o suficiente (exercícios costumam ter requisitos e limitações não usuais, então pode não ser o que o professor espera). De qualquer forma, não é um exemplo bom porque eu crio o computador, imprimo os dados e depois descarto-o. Faria mais sentido guardar os computadores criados em um array ou lista, por exemplo, mas como o exercício não menciona nada disso, vou deixar assim mesmo.

---

Outra alternativa é ter outra classe que sabe como imprimir um computador. Algo assim:

```
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Printer {

    private static NumberFormat FORMATADOR_PRECO = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(new Locale("pt", "BR"));

    public static void imprimir(Computador c) {
        System.out.println("Placa mãe: " + c.getPlacaMae());
        System.out.println("Processador: " + c.getProcessador());
        System.out.println("Gabinete: " + c.getGabinete());
        System.out.println("Placa de video: " + c.getPlacaDeVideo());
        System.out.println("Mouse: " + c.getMouse());
        System.out.println("Teclado: " + c.getTeclado());
        System.out.println("Headset: " + c.getHeadset());
        System.out.printf("Memória ram: %dGB\n", c.getMemoria());
        System.out.printf("Tamanho da tela: %d'\n", c.getMonitor());
        System.out.printf("Preço: %s\n\n", FORMATADOR_PRECO.format(c.getPreco()));
    }
}
```

E no `for` bastaria fazer:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    Computador c = new Computador();
    System.out.println("Fabricante da placa mãe: ");
    c.setPlacaMae(sc.nextLine());
    // lê todos os dados, igual ao anterior

    // na hora de imprimir, usa o Printer, passando o computador criado
    System.out.println("\n\nCriado o computador:");
    Printer.imprimir(c);
}
```

---

### Validação

Se quiser incluir uma validação, uma opção seria fazer isso na leitura do dado:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    Computador c = new Computador();

    // exemplo de leitura do dado
    while (true) {
        System.out.println("Quantidade de memória: ");
        int memoria = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
        if (memoria >= 1) {
            c.setMemoria(memoria);
            break; // interrompe o while
        } else {
            System.out.println("Valor inválido, informe um valor acima de 1 GB!");
        }
    }
}
```

Outra opção é cada método *setter* lançar uma exceção em caso de dado inválido, e na leitura você verifica se o erro aconteceu, e tenta de novo se for o caso:

```
public class Computador{
    // campos, getters, setters, etc

    // exemplo de setter que valida o dado
    public void setMemoria(int memoria) {
        if (memoria >= 1) {
            this.memoria = memoria;
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Valor inválido, informe um valor acima de 1 GB!");
        }
    }
}

// na leitura dos dados
while (true) {
    try {
        System.out.println("Quantidade de memória: ");
        c.setMemoria(Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine()));
        break;
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

---

### Construtores

Quanto ao fato de criar 10 construtores, isso é bem questionável. Para fins de satisfazer o exercício, teria que ser (imagino) algo assim:

```
public Computador() {} // construtor vazio

public Computador(String placaMae) { // construtor com a placa mãe
    this.placaMae = placaMae;
}

public Computador(String placaMae, String processador) { // com placa mãe e processador
    this.placaMae = placaMae;
    this.processador = processador;
}

etc...
```

E na hora de criar um computador você poderia fazer algo como:

```
System.out.println("Fabricante da placa mãe: ");
String placaMae = sc.nextLine();
Computador c = new Computador(placaMae);
// continua lendo os demais dados...
```

Ou, para usar o construtor que recebe a placa mãe e o processador, guarde essas 2 informações em variáveis e depois chame o construtor passando-as, etc.

Mas toda essa ideia já está meio errada, na minha opinião. Claro que sem requisitos reais, só dá para especular, mas será que faz sentido criar um computador sem nenhuma configuração? Ou só com a placa mãe, mas sem as demais informações? Em um caso real, só deveriam ter os construtores que fazem sentido (ou seja, que criam um computador com todas as informações necessárias para ser uma instância válida). Como é um exercício, os requisitos no fundo são "aquilo que o professor pediu", então se é para criar 10 construtores, fazer o que.

O mesmo vale para *getters* e *setters*. Nem todo campo precisa deles. Alguns você só quer obter e não pode mudar, outros pode ser o contrário. Uma vez criado um computador, você pode mudar o nome do fabricante? E a placa mãe? A memória talvez (depende do fabricante), e por aí vai.

Talvez já sejam questões mais "avançadas", mas de qualquer forma, acho importante ir pensando nelas desde já, para não pegar esses "vícios" de criar *getters* e *setters* e construtores para tudo sem necessidade. Para se aprofundar no assunto, leia [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73530/112052), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/44739/112052) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/25995/112052).

Comment: Muito obrigado cara, me ajudou demais. Vou aproveitar e ler o que você sugeriu.

Esse é um segundo arquivo que crio para testar, por isso o nome da classe estava estranho :)